# PII best practices

Tags: encryption, appsec

I'm looking for some guidance and advice on data security best practices, specifically on how to best separate, store and secure personal identifiable information from other data. The background is that we need some data reported by users to run our ML models, so that data would need to be available on the backend. However, we do not need any PII (e.g. name or some preferences), so I thought we should just store the PII data on the users device (and potentially on the user's device manufacturer provided cloud storage, e.g. CloudKit for iOS), and possibly encrypt it there too. That way an attacker could potentially break into the backend, but they would never be able to match the data we have there to any specific person.

Does that sound plausible? Are there better ways to do this?

Cheers!

Comment: It is not clear to me. If you *"do not need any PII"* then why do you want to store these PII in the first place?

Comment: There are situations where the user might need to exchange some PII with a 3rd party, e.g. they might need to let a 3rd party know how to contact them via phone. So the user would need to provide that information and the 3rd party would need to store it on their device. But we as the supplier of the software do not need to know anyone's phone number.

Comment: If the 3rd party needs it then let the 3rd party deal with the problem. Why does the user needs to provide you with the data instead of letting the user provide these data to the 3rd party only?